# Printing an array on a certain line

Tags: java, arrays

I need help printing the array, I need to print 6 items per line and switch to a next line for the seventh and following numbers. Also who do i Enter numbers into an array without defining how many numbers will be entered?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many grades do you want to enter?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[num];
        System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " grades now.");
        for (int grades = 0 ; grades < array.length; grades++ ) 
        {
            array[grades] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("These are the grades you have entered.");
        printArray(array);
    }

    public static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " \t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to see if you are on the 7th line just check your iterator against 7. If you want to see if you are on a multiple of 7, then test for modula (%) 7 == 0

Comment: println will print and go to the next line, print will not... (unless you print the carriage return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need help printing the array, I need to print 6 items per line and switch to a next line for the seventh and following numbers.

From this question, it seems to indicate that you want the output to look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 ... n
```

This can be achieved quite simply.

**Option 1 - The classic If statement**

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    System.out.print(array[x]);

    if(x == 5) {
        // 5 because we're counting from 0!
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - Using the Ternary operator to keep it on one line**

**NOTE**: This is more or less the same. It's just nice to be complete in these sorts of answers.

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    System.out.print(array[x] + x == 5? "\n":"");
}
```

**Edit**

If you meant that you want 6 items on each line, like so:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
...
```

Then you can use the `%` (The modulus operator) to print out a new line on every output. This is actually quite easy to change, but you'll need to make sure that you're checking the value *before* you're outputting the content. This can be shown in [this IDEOne](http://ideone.com/U7yB0H).

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operator (%) to break to a new line line:

```
public static void printArray(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i % 6 == 0)  // if you don't want the initial newline, check for i > 0
            System.out.println()
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " \t");
    }
}
```

you can also use `printf()` method to format the line; which is probably better:

```
System.out.printf("%5d", arr[i]);
```

The reason why this is better, is because you can easily format the output to a specific justification, column width, etc., which will make your output look better.